# Generic TCP, UDP, HTTP Reverse-Proxy Setup

Tags: http, tcp, scripting, reverse-proxy, hipache

I enjoy [hipache](https://github.com/dotcloud/hipache), a HTTP reverse-proxy that uses Redis, but cannot support (in my experience) TCP. I really like easily scripting my basic (e.g. HTTP) reverse proxy needs, but the lack of any UDP or TCP reverse proxy is causing problems--I constantly have to remember that foo.com:49182 is mysql, instead of just using mysql-test.foo.com.

The only 'solution' I can think of is to set up a TCP reverse proxy on a different port (maybe 8080) and use that for the applications that need direct TCP proxying e.g. mysql-test.foo.com:8080. Similarly for UDP.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author of hipache has some ideas. See 
https://github.com/samalba/hipache-nginx
and 
http://blog.dotcloud.com/under-the-hood-dotcloud-http-routing-layer

Maybe you can have a combination of [haproxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/) and nginx as others follows.

Comment: That's where I'm leaning after lots of thought. Thanks for linking the project fork, it may save me some time